# Navigation/TabBarController disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication, 3dtouch

I`m using this code in `AppDelegate` for make a shortcut when you long press the app before its launch.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if(shortcutItem.type == "com.skalstad.addStuff")
    {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
        let add =  sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddTableViewController") as! AddTableViewController

        let root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

        root?.presentViewController(add, animated: false, completion: {() -> Void in


            completionHandler(true)


        })
    }
}
```

When i open the shortcut, the `viewController` is full screen,no `NavigationController` or `TabBarController`. Anyone with this same issue or have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're presenting a view controller modally, which means no tab bar controller and no navigation controller.

If you want to see either, you can either [use a segue programatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW5)  (see the "Initiating a Segue Programmatically" section of that document) to push to your "`AddTableViewController`" or connect your tab bar controller to an outlet and then select the tab that has your "`AddTableViewController`".  No need to instantiate your main storyboard again (it's already loaded into memory when your app is launched).